# Locking: Allow INSERT but not UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, locking

I would like to lock a table: `INSERT` should be allowed, but `UPDATE` should be disabled.

I am using a current PostgreSQL version.

I read [Advisory Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) and [explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html). Maybe I am blind, but I could not find a suitable solution for my goal.

Here are details to my use case:

There is a table which is roughly like logging: Several processes add new rows to the table at the same time.

Once in a hour a script processes the data which was added.

Now I want to be sure that this script has a fixed working set. No modifications should be done to the rows which the script is working on. But it is ok if new rows get added while the scripts run. These rows get processes with the next call of the script.

Comment: There is no table lock mode which does this.  What is the other task (the one that takes out this intended lock mode) doing while it holds it the putative lock?

Comment: A brute force approach would be to do a `select * from the_table for update`

Comment: add an instead of trigger for updates, then either throw an error, silently rollback or just do nothing.

Comment: You probably need to specify more closely, what you want to achieve exactly ...

Comment: A textbook example of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter (and other): I updated the question and added my use case.

Comment: It's not obvious why there should be *any* modifications to rows of a table with "logging" information. Would seem like there should only be inserts to begin with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can use [row-level locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) to write-lock all rows currently in the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl FOR UPDATE;
```

Or similar.

But that prevents all writes, including `DELETE`, not only `UPDATE` - for the duration of the lock. And there is the remaining question about rows inserted after that: shouldn't those be protected from `UPDATE`, too?

The way you phrased it (*"`INSERT` should be allowed, but `UPDATE` should be disabled."*), it sounds like a more general matter of privilege management with **[`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) and [`REVOKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html)**, rather than locking.

Something like:

```
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE public.tbl TO public;
REVOKE UPDATE ON TABLE public.tbl FROM public;
```

Or:

```
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE public.tbl TO specific_role;
REVOKE UPDATE ON TABLE public.tbl FROM specific_role;
```

The actual commands depend on who has been `GRANT`ed privileges in the first place, and who shall be prevented to update now.
Don't forget the special case of the table *owner*. [The manual on `GRANT`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS)

> There is no need to grant privileges to the owner of an object
> (usually the user that created it), as the owner has all privileges by
> default. (The owner could, however, choose to revoke some of their own
> privileges for safety.)

While locks only last for the duration of a transaction, the effect is permanent - until changed explicitly. Also, locks are expensive. `GRANT` / `REVOKE` is almost cost-free.

You need the necessary privileges. Either be the owner of the table, be member in the role owning the table, be a superuser, or you have been granted the same privilege `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pg_try_advisory_lock()`. See [Advisory Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)